# Complement of strictly less than (n-1)-dimensional set is connected?

Tags: path-connected, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subset such that its Hausdorff dimension is strictly less than $n-1$. Is it then true that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ is (path-)connected?
Intuitively if we consider $\mathbb{R}^2$, then we need at least a line (i.e. something $1$-dimensional) to disconnect the space. Similarly in $3$-dimensions one would require something $2$-dimensional and so on.

In my particular case I have a subset which is a countable union of smoothly embedded $1$-manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and my intuition tells me the complement must be path-connected, but I was not able to put my intuition into a rigorous proof.

The problem seems rather intuitive, so I guess there will be some results in the literature already? If anyone has a hint I would appreciate it.

Kind Regards Dennis

Answer (score 1):

As I found out the answer is yes, provided $A$ is a closed subset, as was for instance discussed in the following [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730111/can-a-set-of-hausdorff-codimension-2-disconnect-a-connected-open-set).